# Series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{60n^{2}-43n+8}{n^{4}}\right)\binom{4n-2}{2n-1}\binom{2n}{n}^{-4}=2\zeta(2)$

Tags: reference-request, summation, pi

Recently through Integer Relation Algorithms I was able to find the following Series For $\pi$ :
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{60n^{2}-43n+8}{n^{4}}\right)\binom{4n-2}{2n-1}\binom{2n}{n}^{-4}=2\zeta(2)$$

I have checked it upto $1000$ digits of precision.

Is this Series known in Literature?, if it is I would appreciate it if someone could provide the source.


Here is the Wolfram Command for those interested :

`N[Sum[((60n^2-43n+8)/(n^4))Binomial[4n-2,2n-1]Binomial[2n,n]^{-4},{n,1000}],1000]-2Zeta[2]`

EDIT :

It seems the Degree $8$ Variation has been found by Almkvist in 2010 :

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{60n^{2}-43n+8}{n^{4}}\right)\binom{4n-2}{2n-1}\binom{2n}{n}^{-4}=2\zeta(2)$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{5460n^{4}-8341n^{3}+4864n^{2}-1280n+128}{n^{8}}\right)\ \binom{4n-2}{2n-1}\binom{2n}{n}^{-8}=6\zeta(4)$$

Rewriting such that the Binomial Terms are the same we get this.

Now I thought that a $\zeta(6)$ variation could be found such that we have $n^{12}$ in the denominator, $-12$ the power of Central Binomial Coefficient and a degree $6$ Polynomial in the numerator.

But no luck using Integer Relation Algorithms.

Comment: Just a remark: $\Gamma(\frac14)\Gamma(\frac34)=\pi\sqrt2$.

Comment: @nejimban Thank you, I totally missed that.

Comment: +1 Very nice! Since $\Gamma(1/4)\Gamma(3/4) = \pi\sqrt2$, your sum actually is $\dfrac{\pi^2}3=2\zeta(2)$. There is one very similar formula for $9\zeta(4)$. Give me a while to type it.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Thank you for the comment, I was using FindIntegerNullVector with Gamma and $\pi$, forgot to include $\pi^2$

Comment: Thank you for asking this question. I gotta go, but I will try tonight to obtain it. It looks challenging.

Comment: Low weight case may be considered first, like $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{145n^2-104n+18}{n^3(2n-1)\binom{2n}{n}
\binom{3n}{n}^2  } =\frac{\pi^2}{3}$ generated by $\,_2F_1$.

Comment: @SetnessRamesory  The _shifted_ form of your series for $\pi^2$ yields one for $\pi$. Kindly see Addendum in the edited answer. Can you give more similar identities for $\pi^2$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the OP's formula *A* for $\zeta(2)$, there is a *very* [similar one](https://web.archive.org/web/20230326021917/https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/0019) *B* for $\zeta(4)$,

\begin{align}
A &=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\binom{4n-2}{2n-1}\binom{2n}{n}^{-4}\frac{(60n^{2}-43n+2^3)}{n^{4}}\\
A &=\frac{\pi^2}3=2\,\zeta(2)\\[8pt]
B &=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\binom{4n-3}{2n-1}\binom{2n}{n}^{-8}\frac{(5460n^4-8341n^3+2^8(19)n^2-2^8(5)n+2^7)}{n^8}\\
B &=\frac{\pi^4}{30}=3\,\zeta(4)
\end{align}

derived by Almkvist by <strike>flipping</strike> *shifting* the sole Ramanujan-type formula for $1/\pi^4$ found by Jim Cullen in 2010. (The terminology "shifting" is used by Guillera in "[*Ramanujan Series with a Shift*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.02023)".)

I wonder if, using the OP's formula for $\pi^2$, it may be possible to shift it to get a Ramanujan-type formula for $1/\pi^2$?

---

**I. Update** (an hour later)

Turns out Formula *A* is indeed a *shifted* version of one Guillera's formulas for $1/\pi^2$. Given the polynomial in $A$,

$$60(n+k)^2-43(n+k)+8$$

Let $k=1/2$, and it transforms to $\frac12(120n^2+34n+3)$. We do the same to the polynomial in $B$, and we get *two* Ramanujan-type formulas,

\begin{align}
\frac1{\pi^2} &=\frac{1}{2^{5}}\,\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_3(n)\,\frac{120n^2+34n+3}{2^{4n}}\\[4pt]
\frac1{\pi^4} &=\frac{1}{2^{11}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_2(n)\frac{43680n^4+20632n^3+4340n^2+466n+21}{2^{12n}}
\end{align}

where,

$$b_3(n)=\frac{\big(\tfrac12\big)_n^3\,\big(\tfrac14\big)_n\,\big(\tfrac34\big)_n}{n!^5}, \quad c_2(n)=\frac{\big(\tfrac12\big)_n^7\,\big(\tfrac14\big)_n\,\big(\tfrac34\big)_n}{n!^9} \quad $$

with [*Pochhammer symbol*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html) $(x)_n$.

To recap, the formula for $1/\pi^4$ was found by Cullen and Almkvist <strike>flipped</strike> *shifted* it to $\pi^4$. For this post, it was the reverse: the OP found $\pi^2$ and, if we shift it, we recover one of Guillera's formulas for $1/\pi^2$. Suggested further reading for two of Guillera's papers can be found in the comments.

---

**II. Addendum** (days later)

"*Shifting*" an identity does not necessarily lead to a shifted value that is the reciprocal of the first. It may be a totally different value. For example, we use the one by Setness Ramesory in the comments and express it with Pochhammer symbols $(x)_n$,

$$F(k)=\small\sum_{n=1}\frac{\big(\tfrac12+k\big)_n\,\big(1+k\big)_n^3}{\big(\tfrac13+k\big)_n^2\,\big(\tfrac23+k\big)_n^2}\, \frac{145(n+k)^2-104(n+k)+18}{(n+k)^3\,(2(n+k)-1)}\,
\left(\frac{2}{27}\right)^{2(n+k)}$$

If $k=0$, then naturally we get Ramesory's,

$$F(0) = \frac{\pi^2}{3}\qquad$$

But if $k=\frac12$, then the shifted value is *not* the reciprocal, but $\pi$ is an exponent *lower* and with an added rational,

$$\qquad F\big(\tfrac12\big) = \frac{4\pi}{3}-14\left(\frac23\right)^3$$

Comment: Considering the Series I found is just a degree $4$ variation, then most likely it would have appeared in literature somewhere.
Also check out my edit once!

Comment: @MiracleInvoker I think Almkvist's formula should be $3\zeta(4)$. And there is a typo in your edit with the binomial sums. Can you verify pls?

Comment: I have changed $4n-3$ to $4n-2$.

Comment: @MiracleInvoker Ah, by slightly revising the binomial sums to be _consistent_ with yours, you get $6\zeta(4)$ while Almkvist was $3\zeta(4)$. Nice! P.S. I figured out the mystery. Your formula is the _flipped_ version of one of Guillera's $1/\pi^2$ formulas. I'll edit my post.

Comment: @MiracleInvoker Try $1/n^6$ and $\zeta(3)$ or $\pi^3$.

Comment: No luck for $\zeta(3)$ even. Maybe it stops here? Also what is this Flipping of Binomial Sums called? This is the first time I am seeing this, is it something trivial?

Comment: @MiracleInvoker I don't completely understand this "flipping" involving binomial sums and Pochhammer symbols myself. But it works, and I know Guillera described it in more detail in one of his papers.  When I wrote that article back in 2010, I only helped flipped Cullen's $1/\pi^4$. If I had done so for Guillera's $1/\pi^2$, I would have recognized your formula more quickly.

Comment: Can you link a paper in which I can read more about this technique?

Comment: @VukStojiljkovic Search Guillera's "Series closely related to Ramanujan formulas for pi" (2003) & "Ramanujan series with a shift" (2018). What he did was let $n \to n+1/2$ which is what I did to Cullen's $1/\pi^4$ formula in a [2010 article](https://web.archive.org/web/20230326021917/https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/0019) and simplified by Almkvist using binomial sums. This shift may cause a flip from $1/\pi^n \to \pi^n$, or the series may sum to different constants like [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20230326021900/https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/0016) or in the 2018 paper.

Comment: @MiracleInvoker I gave 6 examples of this "shifting" (Guillera's better word for "flipping") in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4798813/4781). You may recognize the polynomial of the 4th one.

Comment: @VukStojiljkovic More examples of this technique in this [new post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4798813/4781).